# Questions on Proof of Sequence Unboundedness by Comparison

Tags: sequences-and-series

In my studies I was asked to show that the following sequence is unbounded above:

$$a_n = n^2 - 10n$$

It can be easily shown that $a_n$ increases starting with the fifth term. I decided to prove that the sequence was unbounded above by comparing it with the following sequence:

$$b_n = n$$

Which we know is unbounded above, since we can always choose an n such that $b_n > k$ for any k (for instance by choosing $n = k + 1$). Since $a_n > b_n$ for all $n \ge 11$ can we say that $a_n$ is also unbounded above? It seems sensible, but it bothers me as non-rigorous. Is there a general theorem that establishes that you can proof unboundedness by comparison? The one that I have in my text says that this works for everywhere-increasing sequences, but in this case $b_n$ is not everywhere increasing.

Edit: Sign change

Comment: Did you want to have $a_n=n^2-10n$?

Comment: Oops! yes. Edited

Comment: Maybe just observe that it's $n(n-10)$, and for $n > 10$ this exceeds $n$.

Comment: is the upper bound any real or an integer?

Comment: $\forall n\;(n\geq 11\implies $ $(n>0\land n-10\geq 1)\implies$ $ (n(n-10)\geq n\cdot 1=n)).$... Therefore$ \sup_{n\in \mathbb N}( n^2-10n) \geq$ $ \sup_{n\geq 11}(n^2-10n) \geq$ $ \sup_{n\geq 11}n=\infty. $ ... Seems rigorous to me.

Comment: If the sequence $(b_n)_n$ is unbounded above, then a comparison to $(a_n)_n$ will show that $(a_n)_n$ is unbounded above, provided that the set of $n$ for which $a_n<b_n$ is a finite set..

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo The bound is any Real.

Answer (score 1):

It can be $n^2-10n$ or $n^2-10000000n$ this changes nothing. What's important is that $n^2$ is growing faster so it ultimately constitutes the main contribution to the sum.

To show that, you can factor $n^2$ and the expression become $a_n=n^2(1-\frac{10}{n})$

We see that for $n>20$ for instance $1-\frac{10}n>\frac 12$ and we get $a_n>\frac 12n^2\to+\infty$.

---

About your question in comment :

Yes, this is a perfectly rigourous proof to claim :

$b_n$ unbounded above and $\forall n\ge n_0,\ a_n>b_n\implies\ a_n$  unbounded above.

The first terms of the sequence are of no importance, so if the inequality is true only for $n\ge 5$ or $n\ge 11$ or $n\ge 124674$ this is unsubstantial, the conclusion stays valid.

Let examine the definitions :

- $b_n\to+\infty\iff\forall A>0,\exists n_0\mid \forall n\ge n_0,\ b_n\ge A$

So if we have $\forall n\ge k,\ a_n\ge b_n$

Then if we choose $n_1=\max(n_0,k)$ then $\forall n\ge n_1,\ a_n\ge b_n\ge A$

And we have proved $\forall A>0,\exists n_1\mid \forall n\ge n_1,\ a_n\ge A\iff a_n\to+\infty$

- $b_n$ unbounded above $\iff \forall n_0,\forall A>0,\exists n_1\ge n_0\mid  b_{n_1}\ge A$

So if we have $\forall n\ge k,\ a_n\ge b_n$

Then if we choose $n_1=\max(n_0,k)$ then $\exists n_2\ge n_1\ge n_0\mid a_{n_2}\ge b_{n_2}\ge A$

And we have proved $\forall n_0, \forall A>0,\exists n_2\ge n_0\mid a_{n_2}\ge A\iff a_n$ unbounded above.

Of course $a_n$ unbounded above is weaker than $a_n\to+\infty$, so we generally try to prove the latest first by comparing our sequence to one which is known to diverge to infinity.

Comment: Forgive me, I think the original post was a little vague. More directly put, the question is this:

Comment: @JorgeMedina I'd like to answer, but the question appears truncated in the comment ?

Comment: Apologies. The question is this:
Given the sequence $a_n = n^2 - 10n$ does this count as a proof that $a_n$ is unbounded above?

1. Assume it has been proven that the sequence $b_n = n$ is unbounded above.

2. $a_n \ge b_n \forall n \ge 11$

3. $\exists k$ such that $a_n \ge b_n \forall n \ge k$

4. $\therefore a_n$ is unbounded above

Comment: @JorgeMedina I have extended my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Then $a_n=(n-5)^2+25$. For $n\ge 5$, $a_n$ is increasing, so $a_n\ge a_5+(n-5)$ for $n\ge5$, that is $a_n\ge n-30$.